# Add scope and extension to endpoint in code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a discovery endpoint for my WCF service.

In my discovery client I need to search for all services of specific type.
For this purpose I'm thinking to use Scope feature and WCF service metadata extension.

```
// Create DiscoveryClient
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
// Find ICalculatorService endpoints            
FindCriteria findCriteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(IAgent));
findCriteria.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
findCriteria.Scopes.Add(new Uri("net.tcp://cybertech.com/CallTesting/AgentService/1/Cisco"));
FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
```

Is it possible to configure service endpoint metadata like Scope and Extensions in code.
If yes, what is the API for that? I didn't found much on the internet.

I need in-code solution, because I'm hosting service in-code and i'm not using XML configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution to add it in code:

```
var address = CommonMethods.GetIpLocalAddress();

            _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(AgentService), new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/AgentService", address)));

            var endpoint = _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAgent), new NetTcpBinding(), String.Empty);

            var metadataProvider = new CiscoMetaDataProvider();

            var discoveryBehavior = new EndpointDiscoveryBehavior();
            discoveryBehavior.Scopes.Add(new Uri("net.tcp://blablabla.com/CallTesting/AgentService/1/Cisco"));
            discoveryBehavior.Extensions.Add(new XElement("phoneNumber", metadataProvider.GetPhoneNumber()));

            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);

            var discoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint();

            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(discoveryEndpoint);

            ServiceDiscoveryBehavior serviceDiscoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();

            serviceDiscoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());

            _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDiscoveryBehavior);

            _host.Open();
```